# Sort within a dataframe column value

Tags: r, sorting

My data frame looks like below:

```
ID   Name   Products
1    XX     34,21,14
2    XX     11,15,9
```

I want to be able to sort within the products columns so that my output looks like below:

```
ID   Name   Products 
1    XX     14,21,34 
2    XX     9,11,15
```

This will help me to eliminate duplicate rows. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(df1$Products, ","), function(x) paste(sort(as.numeric(x)), collapse = ","))`

Comment: could you give us `dput(head(sample_data))` ? to be sure of the format of the product column.

Comment: Thank you d.b. I had placed the sort way earlier that it sorted the whole column instead of just the value inside the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:2, Name = 'XX', Products = c('11,15,9', '34,21,14'))
df
#>   ID Name Products
#> 1  1   XX  11,15,9
#> 2  2   XX 34,21,14

df[,c('Products')] <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df_in$Products), ","),
                              function(x) paste(sort(as.numeric(x)), collapse = ","))
df
#>   ID Name Products
#> 1  1   XX  9,11,15
#> 2  2   XX 14,21,34
```